# How can I modify this code so that canny edge detector can detect this red mark line?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, edge-detection, matlab-coder, canny-operator

I take an image using Microsoft Kinect. But all time canny edge detector missed that line. I don't know why? how can I detect this line? I attached here raw depth image & output of canny. Don't hesitate about black depth image. it works. When you run my code you will see that in red arrow area of the raw depth image has an edge but after the canny operation, it vanished.

```
A_depth_distance=imread(raw_depth_image);
figure,imshow(A_depth_distance,[0 4500]);

%Filtering the raw depth image Median
filtered_depth_distance=medfilt2(A_depth_distance,[3 3]);
figure,imshow(filtered_depth_distance,[0 4500]);
title('Filtering the raw depth image Median');

%Edge Detection Using Canny Operator
edges_depth_distance=edge(filtered_depth_distance,'canny',[0 .02],4);
figure, imshow(edges_depth_distance); 
title('Image obtained using Canny Operator');
```

Raw Depth Image:

[image: Raw Depth Image]

The output of canny operator:

[image: Output of canny operator]

Comment: You can play with the threshold and the sigma parameters. They are the only parameters you can change in Matlab. Beyond that, I feel a misunderstanding: Canny is not meant to detect 100% of the edges. In image processing, most of the time, algorithms try to imitate/find the information that our eyes can infer from the training we have since childhood. The fact that your eyes see an edge does not mean that the algorithm will find it 100% sure. If you are not happy with the results, you can try other edge detectors or even to design your own. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried many others.but canny works well. but only this cant detect for every image.